# Extra distance travelled along a sine wave path

Tags: geometry, curves

Let's say I have a blue line which is 10 metres long.  I then draw a single cycle of a sine curve along this line, in red which has a maximum distance of 0.1 meter from the line (so an amplitude of 0.1m).

If I walk along the sine curve, I will walk further than 10 metres.  But how do I calculate this new distance travelled?

What about if I increase the frequency so that there are five full cycles along my 10 metre blue line?  How does the frequency affect it, in other words?

Answer (score 2):

HINT

This answer may not help directly for higher frequencies/waves but stating it nevertheless.., the following requires some imagination.

Sinusoidal waves are development of slantly cut cylinder intersections seen as surface development.

If a cylinder radius $a$ is cut at an angle $\alpha$ to radial plane the ellipse axes are $ (a, a \sec \alpha) $ then the ellipse has an eccentricity $ e= \sin \alpha$.

$$ 2 \pi a = 10 m, \quad  a \tan \alpha = \dfrac{.01}{2} ; $$

Solve for $ (a,\alpha, e)$.

The perimeter is $ 4 a \, E(e)$ which a standard result using Elliptic integrals; it can be found by integration or google it for a start.

EDIT1:

Useful to remember the waveform equations of same amplitude $A$ for single and multiple frequencies $n$:

$$ y_1= A \sin \dfrac{2 \pi x}{\lambda}$$

$$ y_n= A \sin \dfrac{2 \pi x\cdot n}{\lambda}$$

Answer (score 1):

You need the arc length formula for this: $\int\sqrt{1+f'(x)^2}dx$ on interval $[0,10]$. What you need to do is establish the formula of your curve, which is not hard to do. After all, you know the period (then use $b=\frac{2\pi}{period}$) and the amplitude as you stated. Anyway, the real problem is that the arc length formula is not going to come out "nice", in the sense that I greatly expect that you are going to deal with an integral that cannot be evaluated in terms of elementary functions. You are then left with an approximation using an TI for example

Comment: Thanks - is there a non-mathematicians' version?  If it approximates the distance then that's fine.

Comment: Of course there is a less "stringent" mathematics version. How much less mathematically you want to go?. You can "avoid" calculus in the following manner: Use increments of $0.1$ for $x$ and calculate the corresponding $y's$ for each increasing $x$. Then use Pythagorean theorem $100$ times $(10/0.1)$ and add up distances. That would be a good approximation. It's a little work but not difficult. You still need to set up your sine formula, also not difficult. (This answers the first part of your question)

Comment: I was hoping for a formula which doesn't require calculus (by which i mean, for example, integrating functions - sorry if that's not calculus, i'm not a mathematician), and into which I can just plug some numbers and carry out only simple operations.  Imagine I'm trying to do it in a computer program where I can only do basic operations, raising to a power, sin, cos and tan and their converses.

Comment: My second approach in my previous comment does not require calculus. The Pythagorean theorem is what you need (remember that famous $a^2+b^2=c^2$ on a right triangle from high school?). I think that is as basic as you can go. To calculate a distance between two points, the formula translates to $c=\sqrt{(0.1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}$. You need  to do that 100 times as you have 100 increments. Then add up. Having something like Excel available would be tremendously helpful

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I guess I was too optimistic for a simple one-hit equation then!

Comment: Unfortunately no. The arc length formula itself is easy, however evaluating it is a pain and generally there are no exact solutions available. We then need to resort to numerical methods, just like in your case...

Comment: Has anyone done a table, I wonder?  Eg with a row for different ratios of the amplitude to the period?  In my case I'd look up the 0.01 row (since my period distance is 100x bigger than the amplitude).